# Typescript conditional generic type in return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How to condition the generic of return type if value is not present?

```
type Foo = {};

class Bar<P extends Foo> {
    static make<P extends Foo>(a?: P): Bar<P> {
        return new Bar();
    }
}

Bar.make() // return Bar<Foo>
```

But I need to do something like:

```
class Bar<P extends Foo> {
    static make<P extends Foo>(a?: P): Bar<P extends undefined ? never : Foo> {
        return new Bar();
    }
}

Bar.make() // return Bar<never>
Bar.make({}) // return Bar<Foo>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a default type `never`.

```
type Foo = {test: number}; // Example implementation of foo, used in test cases below

class Bar<P extends Foo> {
  // Allow P to extend from Foo, then assign never as the default
  static make<P extends Foo = never>(a?: P): Bar<P> {
    return new Bar();
  }
}

const t1 = Bar.make(); // Bar<never>
const t2 = Bar.make({ test: 2 }) // Bar<{test: 2}> (subtype of Foo)
const t3: Bar<Foo> = Bar.make({ test: 2 }); // Bar<Foo> (explicit typecasting to Bar<Foo>)
const t4 = Bar.make({ bazz: 0 }); // Type error, { bazz: 0 } is not assignable to Foo
```

Here a [TypeScript Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgewTAvDA3iKBnEAuGAOwFcBbAIygCcBfAbmGAGMAbAQ22xgCE2qAeAAowoADyyEAJl0QIAfBmAwYuNiACWTGKTYBrKEJHioUmUhgAfIlABu1VNbtU5ACjYB+AoICUBXgMEFdCVlGCooEGIqQmsAdx4+F28GZRoYYBpGJgRCXBgQAEYHfwA6HX0kuhgAemqEgUJbajlmHLyQACZivjK9KBd0fJx8GC6abxq6-35MYYIOmgUXbGJycGgYBAAzeCRvVtyQfIBmPz5+WQU0UvL+waxceZhxqtr6i6QlsQgWTXUj9ZQJgcDSEADm+WQ00u+2yh3yABZulRehVBuQ2AAvTEEAAMz2SkxgABVILBqFQEFQADQYGAY7F454wdRcQgII4cbDqMGENjkFiwEDIWTAIA) to showcase the different outcomes.

Comment: @luky Added some explanation and a playground link :)

Comment: `Foo | never` is identical to `Foo`; did you write it as `Foo | never` for some reason?

Comment: @jcalz Good catch, that's a remnant from testing another approach. Changed the code block - though it wouldn't hurt if you wanted to be really explicit.